# I am trying to filter an alias column, which I know it wont work in the WHERE clause. I need to filter the YEARS >15

Tags: sql, filter

```
select department_id, last_name, round(((sysdate-hire_date)/30)/12, 0) as YEARS
from employees
where YEARS >15;
```

Comment: Just repeat the entire expression again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to the alias in the `WHERE` clause.  One option is to simply repeat the entire round expression:

```sql
SELECT department_id, last_name,
       ROUND(((SYSDATE - hire_date) / 30) / 12, 0) AS YEARS
FROM employees
WHERE ROUND(((SYSDATE - hire_date) / 30) / 12, 0) > 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to repeat the round expression and also you can use `DATEDIFF` which is another option.

```
SELECT department_id, last_name,
       ROUND(((SYSDATE - hire_date) / 30) / 12, 0) AS YEARS
FROM employees 
Where  DATEDIFF(year, hire_date, getdate()) > 15
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Oracle SQL, and datediff is for MySQL, right.  thanks though

Comment: No worries, hope this helps in future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I came up with a resolution this morning

```
select department_id, sum(salary) as "Summary"
from employees
where round(((sysdate-hire_date)/30)/12, 0)>15
group by department_id
order by department_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code

select department_id, sum(salary) as "Summary"
from employees
where round(((sysdate-hire_date)/30)/12, 0)>15
group by department_id
order by department_id;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).